# Issue with <f:viewAction>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

```
  <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="idFacture" value="#{facturemanaged.idFacture}" required="true"/>
        <f:viewAction action="#{facturemanaged.load()}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

However the function load doesn't return any results and my page xhtml show me a warning telling me

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core declared with prefix f but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

My library was declared with `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf` but doesn't work so i changed it to `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` and then the warnings appears and the function load didn't run.

I think that the problem is with `<f:viewAction >` because I tried without this line and everything is good.

My question is why this problem? And what's the best steps to do when I must have `<f:viewAction>`?

Comment: which version of jsf are you using?

Comment: JSF 2.2 netbeans 7.3.1